# How to send object which contains IEnumerable via Refit on NetCore?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, refit

I have to send a request object via Refit which contains 2 IEnumerable and one string, but for some reason I can't send the object forward.

I've tried to use all the paramets from the interface. Ex: [Query(CollectionFormat.Csv)] or Multi / Pipes but no success.

I've also tried to create my own CustomUrlParameterFormatter but unfortunately here I'm stuck, because I don't see a good way to retrieve the name of the property from the object request that I'm sending.

The code for CustomUrlParameterFormatter

```
public class CustomUrlParameterFormatter : IUrlParameterFormatter
    {
        public string Format(object value, ParameterInfo parameterInfo)
        {
            if(value is IEnumerable enumerable)
            {
                var result = ToQueryString(enumerable, parameterInfo.Name);
                return result;
            }

            return string.Empty;
        }

        public static string ToQueryString(IEnumerable query, string parameterName)
        {
            var values = query.Cast<object>().Select(ToString).ToArray();
            var separator = parameterName + "=";

            return values.Any() ? separator + string.Join("&" + separator, values) : "";
        }

        public static string ToString(object value)
        {
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value).Replace("\\\"", "\"").Trim('"');

            return Uri.EscapeUriString(json);
        }


    }
```

The Call from the IService that I'm using

```
        [Get("/TestMethod")]        
        Task<HttpResponseMessage> TestMethod([Query]TestRequestDTO requestDTO, [Header("X-Correlation-ID")] string correlationId);
```

The Request object

```
    public class TestRequestDTO
    {   
        public IEnumerable<long> EnumOne { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<long> EnumTwo { get; set; }
        public string MethodString { get; set; }
    }
```

Also the RefitClient configuration

```
var refitSettings = new RefitSettings();
            refitSettings.UrlParameterFormatter = new CustomUrlParameterFormatter();

services.AddRefitClient<IService>(refitSettings)
                .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(settings.Services.IService));
```

What I'm trying to achieve is something like

```
TestMethod?EnumOne =123&EnumOne =321&EnumTwo=123&EnumTwo=321&methodString=asdsaa
```

and instead I'm receiving other behavior 
without CustomUrlParameterFormatter()

```
TestMethod?EnumOne=System.Collections.Generic.List`1%5BSystem.Int64%5D&EnumTwo=System.Collections.Generic.List`1%5BSystem.Int64%5D&MethodString=sdf
```

Comment: Is there any demo to reproduce your issue? Share us the code which you used to send request with `RefitClient`.

Comment: Hi @TaoZhou I've attached a sample project -> https://github.com/moisoiu/refit

Comment: I think currently it is not supported, you could trace this issue [[QueryParameters] Are broken for classes with IEnumerable properties #587](https://github.com/reactiveui/refit/issues/587)

Comment: I was afraid of that to be honest, but I thought maybe I'm blind and I'm doing something wrong. Will check the opinion of the guys from Refit also. Thanks